# Missing File Xamarin for Androind on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: android, linux, xamarin, rider

I am trying to get a Xamarin-Android app that was created on Linux in Jetbrains Rider to to run on a device from Rider but get the following error:

`Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2465, 3): [MSB4018] /usr/lib/mono/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2465,3): error MSB4018: The "BuildApk" task failed unexpectedly.
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file "/usr/lib/mono/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/lib/armeabi-v7a/libmono-android.debug.so"`

I have followed the instructions here: https://github.com/0xFireball/xamarin-android-linux
I should also note that running native apps from Android Studio works fine, it's just Xamarin with project Rider. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you download the .tar.bz2 archive from the mono-project, and not the .tar.xz file. The latter is missing those files.